# SELECT for VIEW with steped date dependencies

Tags: join, view, mariadb-10.3

I have two tables on a mariadb 13.0 - `values`:

| id | date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-01 | 10 | 100 |
| 2 | 2023-10-02 | 20 | 200 |
| 3 | 2023-10-03 | 30 | 300 |
| 4 | 2023-10-04 | 40 | 400 |
| 5 | 2023-10-05 | 50 | 500 |

and `rates`:

| date | rate1 | rate2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 0.20 | 0.50 |
| 2023-10-04 | 0.40 | 0.60 |
| 2024-01-01 | 0.30 | 0.40 |

I need to create a view which shows the following data:

| date | vr1 | vr2 | svr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 | 2.0 | 50.0 | 52.0 |
| 2023-10-02 | 4.0 | 100.0 | 104.0 |
| 2023-10-03 | 6.0 | 150.0 | 156.0 |
| 2023-10-04 | 16.0 | 240.0 | 256.0 |
| 2023-10-05 | 20.0 | 300.0 | 320.0 |

The values must be multiplied with the rate which is valid for that date. Beginning with 2023-10-04 the new rate must be used.

I have tried the following SQL:

```
SELECT DiSTINCT d.date, 
v.value1 * r.rate1 AS vr1, 
v.value2 * r.rate2 AS vr2,
v.value1 * r.rate1 + v.value2 * r.rate2 AS svr
FROM values AS v INNER JOIN rates AS r 
WHERE v.date >= r.date
```

but get:

| date | vr1 | vr2 | svr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 | 2.0 | 50.0 | 52.0 |
| 2023-10-02 | 4.0 | 100.0 | 104.0 |
| 2023-10-03 | 6.0 | 150.0 | 156.0 |
| 2023-10-04 | 8.0 | 200.0 | 208.0 <= unwanted |
| 2023-10-04 | 16.0 | 240.0 | 256.0 |
| 2023-10-05 | 10.0 | 250.0 | 260.0 <= unwanted |
| 2023-10-05 | 20.0 | 300.0 | 320.0 |

Comment: Which database system and version are you using?

Comment: I am using mariadb 10.3

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), especially #5 and #3. Does `rates (date)` is constrained as unique?

Comment: Yes the dates column is unique